# Groupby and filter based on MAX value of a one column AND CONDITIONALLY topN values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a following data:

```
    individual  groupID  choice     probA     probB
0      9710535        0       0  0.025589  0.008647
1      9710535        2       0  0.036252  0.014684
2      9710535        2       0  0.036252  0.013894
3      9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.030648
4      9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.014804
5      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.021444
6      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.020298
7      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.163837
8      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.085191
9      9710556        1       1  0.034381  0.796679
10     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
11     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
12     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
13     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
14     9710556        0       0  0.025589  0.008647
```

I want to filter data based for every `individual` on `probA` column's max value per each `groupID`, which is `groupID = 5` for `individual` 9710535. However, if that group's size is less than 5, which is the case here (it has only 4 elements), I also want to have rows from other groups top(5 - that group's size) based on column `probB`.

End result should look like this:

```
  individual  groupID  choice     probA     probB
0     9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.030648
1     9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.021444
2     9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.020298
3     9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.163837
4     9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.085191
5     9710556        1       1  0.034381  0.796679
6     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
7     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
8     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
9     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
```

I am working on a custom function approach with this pseudo code:

```py
def custom_filter(df, groub_by = 'individual', 
                  condition_column1 = 'probA', 
                  condition_column2 = 'probB',
                  top_count = 5)
    return filtered_df
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first extract all maximal rows by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` and compare `groupID` with filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['groupID'].eq(df.groupby('individual')['groupID'].transform('max'))
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
    individual  groupID  choice     probA     probB
5      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.021444
6      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.020298
7      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.163837
8      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.085191
9      9710556        1       1  0.034381  0.796679
10     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
11     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
12     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
13     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
```

Then filter out non matched rows by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and sorting by 2 columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df2 = (df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]
           .sort_values(['individual','probB'], 
                        ascending=[True, False]))
print (df2)
    individual  groupID  choice     probA     probB
3      9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.030648
4      9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.014804
1      9710535        2       0  0.036252  0.014684
2      9710535        2       0  0.036252  0.013894
0      9710535        0       0  0.025589  0.008647
14     9710556        0       0  0.025589  0.008647
```

Last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and get top 5 by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) and last sorting by another 2 columns:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .groupby('individual').head()
        .sort_values(['individual','groupID']))
print (df)
    individual  groupID  choice     probA     probB
3      9710535        1       0  0.090057  0.030648
5      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.021444
6      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.020298
7      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.163837
8      9710535        5       0  0.512675  0.085191
9      9710556        1       1  0.034381  0.796679
10     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
11     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.796679
12     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
13     9710556        1       0  0.034381  0.157622
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! This is not the first time you answer my questions here.
Can you please explain to me the logic behind this operation? I want to understand it, so that the next time I do something similar I do it on my own.

Edit: I accidentally pressed post before finishing my comment

Comment: @EmilMirzayev - Answer was edited and also added explanation.

Comment: Did you mean `probA` instead of `groupID` in the following codes? Because I got confused now, the answer is different from the one it was before:

```mask = df['groupID'].eq(df.groupby('individual')['groupID'].transform('max'));
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .groupby('individual').head()
        .sort_values(['individual','groupID']))
```

Comment: @EmilMirzayev Sorry, original answer working correctly?

Comment: yes, it was working correctly. However, this answer is also very informative I need to further play with this second approach to see where it takes me. Many thanks!